Regarding Vakil's Exercise $10.7.A$
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\Frac}{\operatorname{Frac}}$
In exercise 10.7.A of Vakil's Rising Sea we are tasked with showing that if $A$ is an integrable domain then the normalization of $\Spec A$ exists. Constructing what I think to be the normalization is easy enough, indeed I take the integral closure of $\tilde{A}$ in the fraction field $\Frac(A)$, then there is a canonical injection $A\hookrightarrow \tilde{A}$, so we get a dominant morphism $f:\Spec \tilde{A}\rightarrow \Spec A$. Moreover, $\Spec \tilde{A}$ is easily seen to be normal as well.
Now let $Z$ be any integral normal scheme (for my purposes it suffices to restrict to this case), and let $f:Z\rightarrow \Spec A$ be a dominant morphism. Since $f$ is dominant, and both are integral schemes, the map of rings $A\rightarrow \O_Z(Z)$ is injective. But I am unsure of how to show that this somehow factors through a map $\tilde{A}\rightarrow \O_Z(Z)$. There is a hint that I should show that $\O_Z(Z)$ is integrally closed (as it is an integral domain), but I am unsure of how to see this, or how it relates to getting a map which factors through $A'$.
In particular, in Liu's algebraic geometry, there is a proposition that states that if $X$ is integral and normal, then for every open set of $U\subset X$, $\O_X(U)$ is integrally closed. However, I do not understand the proof of this. The proof is as follows:

Let $V$ be an affine open of $U$, and set $B:=O_X(V)$. Suppose that $\alpha\in \Frac(\O_X(U))$, then $\alpha\in \Frac(B)$. Let $\mathbf{I=\text{Ann}((\alpha B+B)/B)}$, then if $I\neq A$, we have $I\subset \mathfrak p$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset B$. As $B_\mathfrak p$ is integrally closed, there exists $s\in B\smallsetminus \mathfrak p$ such that $s\alpha\in B$. It follows that $s\in I$, a contradiction, hence $1\in I$ and $\alpha\in \O_X(V)$. As this is true for every open affine we have that $\alpha \in \O_X(U)$.

So my confusion with this proof starts with the definition of $I$, and then really just doesn't let up at all. First of all, how is $I$ even an ideal of $B$? It just seems to be the annihilator of the quotient module $\langle 1,\alpha\rangle/B$, where $\langle 1,\alpha\rangle$ is generated over $B$, and so I don't see how this is contained in $B$. Moreover, why does $B_\mathfrak p$ being integrally closed imply that there is an $s\in B\smallsetminus \mathfrak p$ such that $s\alpha\in B$? Since $B$ is integral domain, $B\subset B_\mathfrak p$, so shouldn't this just be true regardless of the integral closure of $B_\mathfrak p$? Finally, why does $I$ being the whole ring imply that $\alpha\in B=\O_X(V)$ and why does this holding true for every open affine then imply that $\O_X(U)$ is integrally closed?
Sorry, I know this a lot but I am just very confused by this proof in general. Importantly as stated earlier, I then don't understand how this is supposed to give a ring homomorphism $\tilde{A}\rightarrow \O_Z(Z)$.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Regarding the '$I$ being an ideal of $B$' part: it is the Ann of a $B$-module, which is always an ideal of $B$. Recall that $Ann(M)$ is defined as ${b \in B | bM=0}$.

Regarding the final part: given an injection of rings $A \to B$, if $B$ is integrally closed, we would have an injection $\tilde{A} \to B$.

@AprilGrimoire Oh is the $/B$ notation not a quotient but just saying annihilator over $B$, i.e. viewing this as a $B$ module?

Yes it is a quotient. Both $\alpha B + B$ and $B$ are $B$-modules, and their quotient as $B$-module also has a $B$-module structure.

By why consider the quotient? I ended up figuring this out, but chose a different ideal, namely ${b\in B:\alpha \cdot b\in B}$, are these the same somehow?

Yeah that's the same. Think about the definition, it's straightforward.
